# "Warning 1: All options related to creation ignored in update mode" (GDAL)

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, vrt, in-memory

I am attempting to clip a raster using a polygon file (shapefile) and to save the result in memory. I succeed to do it using gdal.Warp and the option `format=VRT` using the following code. Please note that before using `gdal.Warp`, I use a function to fix conflict geometry of my shapefile.

```py
 ## SAVING GDAL.WARP RESULT WITH VRT

from osgeo import ogr, gdal

# input data
raster = file.tif
raster = gdal.Open(raster)
shp = polygon.shp


# function to fix conflict geometries
def clean_shapefile(shp):
    shp = ogr.Open(shp, 1)
    layer = shp.GetLayer()

    for feature in layer:
        geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
        if not geom.IsValid():
            feature.SetGeometry(geom.Buffer(0))
            layer.SetFeature(feature)
            assert feature.GetGeometryRef().IsValid()

    layer.ResetReading()
    assert all(feature.GetGeometryRef().IsValid() for feature in layer)


# function to clip raster by a polygon (shapefile)
def clip_raster(raster, shp):
    clean_shapefile(shp)  
    result = gdal.Warp("", raster, cutlineDSName=shp, cropToCutline=True, dstNodata=0, format="VRT")
        return result

# result
clipped_raster = clip_raster(raster, shp)
```

However, VRT is quiet slow and I want to save the clipped raster using the MEM driver of GDAL (apparently faster).

Problem: I get the following error when running `gdal.Warp`:

> Warning 1: All options related to creation ignored in update mode.

Final result is 1 while I want a new `gdal` dataset. I believed it was due to the `gdal.Open` reading option (`GA_ReadOnly = 0` VS `GA_Update = 1`), so I tried option 1 (`GA_Update`) but nothing changed. What is wrong with my code?

```py
 ## SAVING GDAL.WARP RESULT WITH THE MEM DRIVER FROM GDAL

from osgeo import ogr, gdal

# input data
raster = file.tif
raster = gdal.Open(raster)
shp = polygon.shp


# function to fix conflict geometries
def clean_shapefile(shp):
    shp = ogr.Open(shp, 1)
    layer = shp.GetLayer()

    for feature in layer:
        geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
        if not geom.IsValid():
            feature.SetGeometry(geom.Buffer(0))
            layer.SetFeature(feature)
            assert feature.GetGeometryRef().IsValid()

    layer.ResetReading()
    assert all(feature.GetGeometryRef().IsValid() for feature in layer)


# function to clip raster by a polygon (shapefile)
def clip_raster(raster, shp):
    clean_shapefile(shp)
    array = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    array = array.ReadAsArray()
    x_pixels = array.shape[1]
    y_pixels = array.shape[0]
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("MEM")
    dataset = driver.Create("", x_pixels, y_pixels, 1)

    world_file = raster.GetGeoTransform()
    proj = raster.GetProjection()
    dataset.SetGeoTransform(world_file)
    dataset.SetProjection(proj)
    dataset.FlushCache()

    result = gdal.Warp(dataset, raster, cutlineDSName=shp, cropToCutline=True, dstNodata=0)
    return result

# result
clipped_raster = clip_raster(raster, shp)
```